# NodeJS Sessions being shared for some reason

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies, bcrypt

I followed a tutorial regarding implementing sessions in express and it works fine for one user. My issue only occurs with multiple users. As soon as I log into one account, the other tab in which I plan to log in with a different user, is immediately overridden by the first upon refresh.If I log in to each one at the same time, they have their own unique cookie, but upon refresh they share the cookie of the most recent user to login.
I'm not sure why the more recent login is overriding the previous one, I don't see what code could be causing the issue. How would I go about having this work as intended? I would like to be able to have multiple unique users logged in with their own sessions.

app.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
}

var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
//const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
//const dotenv2 = require('dotenv')
const flash = require('express-flash');
const session = require("express-session");
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
//const { cookie } = require('express-validator');
const User = require("./models/user");
const mongoDb = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

mongoose.connect(mongoDb, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "mongo connection error"));


const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
initializePassport(passport,
  async(username) => {
   let users = await User.find().populate("friendsList").sort({id:1}).exec();
   //console.log(users);
   return users.find(user => user.username === username);
 },
  async(id) => {
   let users = await User.find().populate("friendsList").sort({id:1}).exec();
   console.log(users.find(user => user.id === id));
   return users.find(user => user.id === id);
 }
);

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max).toString();
}


var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
  secret: getRandomInt(100).toString(),
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
//app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


app.get('/', checkAuthLogin, async(req, res, next) => {
  res.render('login.pug');
});

app.get('/homepage', checkAuthHomepage, async(req, res, next) => {
  //console.log(users)
    res.render('homepage.pug');

  
});

app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/homepage',
  failureRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash:true
}));


app.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
  console.log("Here");
try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password:hashedPassword,
      image:"",
    });
    user.save();
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch {
  res.redirect("/register");
}
//console.log(users);
});

app.delete('/logout', (req,res) => {
  req.logOut((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
})

function checkAuthHomepage(req,res,next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
}

function checkAuthLogin(req,res,next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect('/homepage');
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
}

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

passport-config.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


function initialize(passport, getUserByUsername, getUserById) {
    console.log("testing");
    const authenticateUser = async (username, password, done) => {
        const user = await getUserByUsername(username);
        //console.log("User searched");
        //console.log( user.password + " " + password);
        if(user == null) {
            //console.log("User: " + user);
            return done(null, false, { message:' No user with that name found' });
        }

        try {
            const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            if (result) {
                //console.log(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password));
                return done(null,user);
            } else {
                console.log("incorrect password");
                console.log( user.password + " " + password);
                return done(null,false, { message: 'Incorrect password' });
            }
        }
        catch (e){
            return done(e);
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({username: 'username'},
    authenticateUser));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
     //console.log(user.id + " first");
     done(null, user.id);
    })
    passport.deserializeUser((id,done) =>  {
        //console.log(id + " second");
        return done(null, getUserById(id));
})           
}
module.exports = initialize
```

Comment: You are a single user. All tabs in your browser share the same cookies. Use a different browser or browser profile or open an incognito window to get a second session.